# regex to replace thatgs containing text

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I'm writing a quick php script and I'm facing the following issue.

I need to go through an html code, find the following "type of line"

```
<p>2:45 text goes here</p>
```

where 2:45 is a timestamp, and text goes here is a variable text and replace it with

```
<li>same timestamp same text goes here</li>
```

cant do a str replace as there are many `<p>`s in the html, reason why I'm looking for a regex pattern.

also I noticed I have another possible match which is:

```
<p>43:41 - text goes here</p>
```

as long as I can just change the opening p to li and remove the dash that will make my day.

I'm fairly bad at regex so I really cant wrap my head around it, so any help is highly appreciated.

Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Match

```
<p>(\d+:\d+ ((?!<\/p>).)+)<\/p>
```

in other words, a `<p>` followed by a timestamp, eventually ending in `</p>` capturing the whole text inside the `<p>` in a group, and replace with the captured group in a `<li>`:

```
<li>$1</li>
```

https://regex101.com/r/sC8RfZ/1

```
$str = '<p>2:45 text goes here</p>
<p>43:41 - text goes here</p>';
$str = preg_replace('/<p>(\d+:\d+ ((?!<\/p>).)+)<\/p>/','<li>$1</li>',$str);
echo $str;
```

Comment: now how would I go through the text a 2nd time, and find a bunch of <li></li> and wrap around the bunch the <ul> bunch of list items </ul>
?